# Posting to YouTube API with jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to post a request to the google authSub for youtube. I use jQuery for AJAX posts etc. When I make the POST I get a 405 error: "405 Method Not Allowed".

Here is my js:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest",
      beforeSend: function(xhr){
         xhr.setRequestHeader('X-GData-Key', 'key="' + ytKey + '"');
      },
      success: function(oData){
         //alert(oData);
      },
      scope: 'http://gdata.youtube.com',
      alt: 'json',
      next: 'http://' + globalBrand + '/sitecreator/view.do',
      session: 1
   });
```

The page I am using in the API for this is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authsub.html).

Here is what the error looks like:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link to the HTML and JS that you are using? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing but I'm unsure how to implement the ajax js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, here is a solution to the problem. If I make the request with the url built out and assigned as an href to an anchor or call it in window.open(); it works.

```
window.open('https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?scope=http://gdata.youtube.com&next=http://' + globalBrand + '/sitecreator/view.do&session=1');
```

As for why jQuery's method with the ajax was being rejected I know not. It seems to be an issue [elsewhere](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=5b33ea74943e5a54&hl=en) also.

Answer (score 1):

Your data parameters for the request are misplaced see below:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest",
      data: {
        scope: 'http://gdata.youtube.com',
        alt: 'json',
        next: 'http://' + globalBrand + '/sitecreator/view.do',
        session: 1
      },
      beforeSend: function(xhr){
         xhr.setRequestHeader('X-GData-Key', 'key="' + ytKey + '"');
      },
      success: function(oData){
         //alert(oData);
      }

   });
```

Now it may be something youre doing wrong additionally, but this for sure needs to be corrected.

Comment: Ah, wow, can't believe I missed that one. However, I still get the 405 error.

Comment: what are you trying to do with `alt: 'json'` i dont see that in the API link you posted. Also looks like youre missing a header for `Authorization: AuthSub token="<authentication_token>"`

Comment: I just added that for memory purposes for other requests I will be making. I commented it out now and I still get the 405.

Comment: What does the request look like in firebug... You should be bale to check that the headers are correct and the data is encoded properly.

Comment: I added an image to my original question of firebug with the 405 error with the headers.

Comment: This request it to get the authentication token. I do not have it yet.

Comment: Try Removing the header you added for you gdata key. I think you only use that after you have the token.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to error HTTP HEADER OPTIONS in JQuery, this request is ok for me:

```
var word = 'search+word';
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="+word+"&max-results=10&alt=json-in-script&format=5,
        cache: false,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
                //json 'data' var treatment
        },
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown, data){
            alert("Not able to fetch the data due to feed unavailability!!!");
        }
});
```

Reference: http://www.mohammedarif.com/?p=180